# Docker container Django not connecting to postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble starting up the django app. It seems to freeze when it prints out

"System check identified 6 issues (0 silenced)."

I believe this is because django is not connected to the postgresql database. I am really unsure of what the problem could be because it was working fine a year ago, and when I am starting it up now it is broken.

***Here is the output for postgresql from the docker container log***

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*


2022-06-13 03:35:26.151 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request

waiting for server to shut down....2022-06-13 03:35:26.155 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions

2022-06-13 03:35:26.156 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1

2022-06-13 03:35:26.156 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down

2022-06-13 03:35:26.204 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down

 done

server stopped


PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.


initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections

You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or

--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

2022-06-13 03:35:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

2022-06-13 03:35:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2022-06-13 03:35:26.273 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2022-06-13 03:35:26.281 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2022-06-13 03:35:26.290 UTC [60] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-06-13 03:35:26 UTC

2022-06-13 03:35:26.291 UTC [61] FATAL:  the database system is starting up

2022-06-13 03:35:26.297 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

***django docker logs:***

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection

    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect

    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

Here is my ***docker-compose.yml file***

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  postgresql:
    container_name: postgresql

    image: postgres:14.3-bullseye
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345678

  django:
    container_name: django
    build: .
    # command: ENTERYPOINT
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static

    depends_on:
      - postgresql

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx/.
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - django

volumes:
  static_volume:
  postgresql_data:
```

***Django settings for docker postgresql database***

```py
# docker database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '12345678',
        'HOST': 'postgresql',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Django Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN pip install -U pip


COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

COPY ./django-enterypoint.sh /app/

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "django-enterypoint.sh" ]
```

***Django django-enterypoint.sh file***

```bash
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate --no-input

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

# gunicorn wall.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I think you need to wait until the database is ready before you connect. Read this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/